# Is there a way to add key values to a dictionary from another dictionary using user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
assassin_weapons = {'dagger':6,'blade':10,'hidden_blade':7,'sai':7,'tomahawk':11,'spear':9}

assassin_armour = {'chest_guard':21,'gauntlets':6,'boots':9,'hood':12,'cape':16}

def store():

    if char_class == 'Assassin':
        time.sleep(0.6)
        print(assassin_weapons)
        time.sleep(0.6)
        purchase = input("Which item(s) do you want to purchase?: ")
        for key in assassin_weapons:
            if key == purchase:
                Assassin.unequipped.update(**assassin_weapons[key])
                print(Assassin.unequipped)
```

Comment: Some of the code is above where its supposed to be, my mistake.

Comment: I've fixed the code formatting for you, but you will need to edit the question to add some description of what specifically you are trying to do, and what specifically is wrong with this code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is `Assassin.unequipped` you are trying to update?

Answer (score 0):

This loop is unnecessary since you have only one key you don't have to loop though the dictionary to get it.

```py
for key in assassin_weapons:
            if key == purchase:
                Assassin.unequipped.update(**assassin_weapons[key])
                print(Assassin.unequipped)
```

I think what you want to do is, get the item he purchased and take that to the `Assassin.unequipped` dictionary?
If yes then, take that key and value and add that to the new dictionary.

```py
if purchase in assassin_weapons:
   if purchase in Assassin.unequipped:
      Assassin.unequipped[purchase]+=assassin_weapons[purchase]
   else:
      Assassin.unequipped[purchase]=assassin_weapons[purchase]
   # type 1 instead of assassin_weapons[purchase] if you want only one item to purchase
```

Comment: The line `purchase = input("Which item(s) do you want to purchase?: ")` implies that the input **can** contain several keys in one input line, which is another thing for the OP to clear how he is expecting it.

Comment: oh, then he can run the loop for,  `purchase.split()` , his loop didn't make sense to me,  so I improvised, my bad for not seeing the `(s)`